# Jfrog Artifactory Docker push failing with POST EOF Error

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-push

I am pushing docker image from Jenkins to Jfrog after generating it , Its failing with below error, and the image is not uploading to Artifactory.

```
docker push artifactory-test.com:443/docker.images/services/springboot-service:0.1.0-125
The push refers to repository [artifactory-test.com:443/docker.images/services/springboot-service]
28ee81ea3d41: Preparing
545d79dbf3fb: Preparing
93057ef9c239: Preparing
9df4e40561c7: Preparing
3dcf3e1de17c: Preparing
ded7a220bb05: Preparing
ded7a220bb05: Waiting
3dcf3e1de17c: Layer already exists
545d79dbf3fb: Layer already exists
9df4e40561c7: Layer already exists
93057ef9c239: Layer already exists
ded7a220bb05: Layer already exists
28ee81ea3d41: Pushed
Post "https://artifactory-test.com:443/v2/docker.images/services/springboot-service/blobs/uploads/": EOF
```